# Electron .Net App appears blank in Centos 7

Tags: .net, linux, electron, centos7, electron-builder

Electron .Net App is blank in Centos 7 due to GPU issue?

Hi,

I tried the demo blazor app with electron .NET. When I created an rpm installer for the app in .NET 5.0 and Electron .Net 13.5.1, the application worked **fine** without issues after installation. But when I moved to .NET 6.0 and Electron 23.6.1, though I was successfully able to create and install the application the launched application showed blank screen. When I launched the app from the terminal I got the error:

**gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(49)] dri3 extension not supported**

**(node:4193) electron: Failed to load URL: http://localhost:8001/ with error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(Use `BlazorApp --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)**

When I reload the app from view->reload the blank screen goes away and the application is visible. Additionally I am able to create a deb package, install and verify that the application works fine in Ubuntu 20.04. Please help me overcome this issue in Centos 7.

My thanks in advance.